# How to add extra information to PayPalPayment?

Tags: android, paypal, sdk

Is there a way to add extra information to PayPalPayment (for example purchase-id, shipment address and things like that) using Android SDK? I don't need to show this info to the user, I just want to get it from PayPal with purchase information later. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, custom invoice-id/payment-id, shipping address, and funding source selection are not yet available.  However, expect more updates on this soon!  Be sure to watch the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/) for updates.